# Create Markdown flickers job site then does nothing

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The jobs section under **edit cv** is a neat little icon to **Create Markdown** of your cv.  If it is clicked the entire site flickers and takes you to an empty page with just the stackoverflow header.

Here is a screen capture of it's location:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report, a build just went out to prod that fixes this.